# Angular 4 httpClient get items interface cast

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following interface

```
interface IPlacesResult {
  summary: {
    queryTime: number;
    // ...
  };
  results: {
    id: string;
    // ...
    address: {
      streetNumber: number;
      // ...
    };
  }[];
}
```

which I populate using

```
this.http.get<IPlacesResult>(environment.azure.locationService.url ...
```

and then need to filter for distinct values

```
.pipe(
  map(result => {
    const resultsMap = new Map<string, IPlacesResult['results']>();
    result.results.forEach(r => {
      const rKey = PlaceSearchResult.toAddressFull(r.address.streetNumber, r.address.streetName,
        r.address.municipalitySubdivision, r.address.countrySubdivision, r.address.postalCode);
      if (!resultsMap.has(rKey)) {
        resultsMap.set(rKey, r); // FAIL here 
      }
...
```

This fails on the indicated last line, with the message

```
[ts]
Argument of type 
  '{ id: string; type: string; score: number; address: { streetNumber: number; streetName: string; m...' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 
  '{ id: string; type: string; score: number; address: { streetNumber: number; streetName: string; m...'.
Property 'includes' is missing in type 
  '{ id: string; type: string; score: number; address: { streetNumber: number; streetName: string; m...'.
```

I've tried to cast it using the `as` operator but it fails with the same message.

How can I successfully filter the items?

Comment: The `.get()` method in Angular returns an Observable so you'll need to setup the API call and then call it from within a component most likely. From there you can assign the output to a type and interact with it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, maybe :)
This is from within a service where I want to filter out extraneous results and add new one before returning to the component. Solution is below.

Comment: I provided an answer below. Hope it helps, I didn't realize you were trying to keep everything in the service at first. Casting Observables to a certain type out of an API can be tricky sometimes.

Comment: @joshrathke For some reason I can't see your answer, but yes ,casting Observables out of an API is tricky :)
There might be some way to elegantly extract the type using the docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html but I haven't figured it out yet, extracting the interface as per my self-answer does work though, just not as elegant as I'd like :) - Thanks for your help.

Comment: I realized that my answer was incorrect, so I removed it. If you found a solution then awesome! Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, IPlacesResult['results'] is actually an array of type

```
{
  id: string;
  type: string;
  score: number;
  address: {
    streetNumber: number;
    streetName: string;
    municipalitySubdivision: string;
    postalCode: number;
    countrySubdivision: string;
  };
}
```

So to fix this issue we have to extract the type of the element, not the array type.

I'm not sure if it's possible to reference the element type of the array but another way is to extract the type as below

```
interface IResult {
  id: string;
  type: string;
  score: number;
  address: {
    streetNumber: number;
    streetName: string;
    municipalitySubdivision: string;
    postalCode: number;
    countrySubdivision: string;
  };
}


interface IPlacesResult {
  summary: {
    queryTime: number;
    numResults: number;
    totalResults: number;
  };
  results: IResult[];
}
```

Then we can reference IResult individually.